# Parent div, with two children, on of them with exact height, how to give the other child "free left" space as height

Tags: css, html, twitter-bootstrap-3

As title says, I have one parent div, and two children divs(div1 and div2) and lets assume parent div is always 100% of it's own parent. I give to div1 height of 200px for example, what to do to make div2 take other left space as its height, 100% height of parent minus 200px of a sibling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Using only css

You can calculate the height in css for div2

```
div2{
height :calc(100℅ - 200px);
}
```

You can read more about `calc()` at [mozilla documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/calc)

#### JavaScript way

You can check the jsfiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/Netdeamon/9fhjcuc5/2/)

Explanation 
calculate the height of div and div1, and assign the subtracted height to div2

```
var h = document.querySelector("#one").offsetHeight
var h2 = document.querySelector("#two").offsetHeight
document.querySelector("#three").style.height = (h - h2)+"px";
```

Comment: What you think, can I do it with javascript ? Will it be okay ?

Comment: Yes you can surely do it with JavaScript. Let me post a example here in JavaScript

Comment: Sure, will wait :)